# Dynamics 365 Search Resource Availability With Constraints

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I've been trying to add filters to my Search Resource Availability api call following this page: [Search resource availability API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/field-service/search-resource-availability-api)
No matter what I do I can't seem to filter by Organizational Unit.
Here's my http call body:

```json
{
    "Version": "3",
    "IsWebApi": true,
    "Requirement": {
        "msdyn_fromdate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00Z",
        "msdyn_todate": "2021-11-30T23:59:00Z",
        "msdyn_remainingduration": 60,
        "msdyn_duration": 60,
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.msdyn_resourcerequirement"
    },
    "Settings": {
        "ConsiderSlotsWithProposedBookings": false,
        "MovePastStartDateToCurrentDate": true,
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando"
    },
    "ResourceSpecification":{
       "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
        "ResourceTypes@odata.type": "Collection(Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando)",
        "ResourceTypes": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
                "value": "3"
            }
        ],
        "Constraints": {
            "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
            "OrganizationalUnits@odata.type": "Collection(Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando)",
            "OrganizationalUnits":[
                {
                    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
                    "value": "b2054232-a114-ec11-b6e7-000d3a842ab8"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the response I get:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://orga215da53.api.crm3.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/$metadata#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.msdyn_SearchResourceAvailabilityResponse",
    "TimeSlots": [],
    "Resources": [],
    "Related": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
        "TimeSlots@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.crmbaseentity)",
        "TimeSlots": [],
        "Resources@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.crmbaseentity)",
        "Resources": []
    },
    "Exceptions": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando"
    }
}
```

But i KNOW that that organization unit exists in CRM.
I tried changing the odata.type to the actual Organization Unit CRM type (`msdyn_organizationalunit`) but that just gives me an error (`An error occurred while validating input parameters: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null`)
What is it that I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

I'm not sure but maybe "Constraints" should be outside "ResourceSpecification" like:

```
{
"Version": "3",
"IsWebApi": true,
"Requirement": {
    "msdyn_fromdate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00Z",
    "msdyn_todate": "2021-11-30T23:59:00Z",
    "msdyn_remainingduration": 60,
    "msdyn_duration": 60,
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.msdyn_resourcerequirement"
},
"Settings": {
    "ConsiderSlotsWithProposedBookings": false,
    "MovePastStartDateToCurrentDate": true,
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando"
},
"ResourceSpecification":{
   "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
    "ResourceTypes@odata.type": "Collection(Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando)",
    "ResourceTypes": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
            "value": "3"
        }
    ]        
},
"Constraints": {
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
        "OrganizationalUnits@odata.type": "Collection(Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando)",
        "OrganizationalUnits":[
            {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
                "value": "b2054232-a114-ec11-b6e7-000d3a842ab8"
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```